# Remove an entire row from the txt file if a particular extension is found

Tags: replace

> 05/06/2014  04:43 PM           441,640 alias.exe
>
> 05/06/2014  04:43 PM            16,330 alias.pgc
>
> 05/06/2014  04:43 PM             1,603 aliasedit.lsp
>
> 05/06/2014  04:43 PM             4,133 architec.lay
>
> 05/06/2014  04:43 PM             7,479 aspace.lsp
>
> 05/06/2014  04:43 PM            14,752 attout.lsp
>
> 05/06/2014  04:43 PM           122,520 axctextapp.dll
>
> 05/06/2014  04:43 PM           147,096 axRText.dll
>
> 05/06/2014  04:43 PM             4,635 blockq.lsp

this is the content of the txt file then the line containing the .dwg has to be removed and saved.
Any language will do.

Thanks.

Comment: i have tried the findstr and the java file hadling methods

Comment: type CHETAN-RND-7.txt | find /i /v ".dwg" >> 1.txt   this works thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] filetext = File.ReadAllLines("yourfilepath");
int index;
for(int i = 0; i < filetext.Length; i ++)
{
  if(filetext[i].EndsWith(".dwg"))
  {
    index = i;
  }
}

filetext = filetext.Where(w => w != filetext[index]).ToString();
```

This reads your entire file at once and deletes the line with the found extension.
It's in C# and I think you will figure out how to save the edited file to a .txt

Comment: type CHETAN-RND-7.txt | find /i /v ".dwg" >> 1.txt   this worked thanks for the help anywyas